# Drop Processor on APM-Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, pipeline, apm

I am using Elastic APM, but want to drop some data based on service.environment, but seems it not to be working. below is the code under ingest pipeline

```
[
  {
    "drop": {
      "if": "'service.environment' == 'ct1'",
      "description": "Drop documents that contain 'service.environment' == ct1"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition needs to be

```
[
  {
    "drop": {
      "if": "ctx.service.environment == 'ct1'",
      "description": "Drop documents that contain 'service.environment' == ct1"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks A lot. It worked.... missed ctx ;-P